# Remove COMPLETE row if Outlier (e.g. 99% Quantile) is Detected from EVERY Column in a Dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, outliers, quantile

Let's say this is my data frame.

```
MyData <- data.frame(
+     X = sample(10:100, 21),
+     Y = sample(10:100, 21),
+     Z = sample(10:100, 21)
+ )
```

I understand how to print the quantiles of each column, either with `sapply` or `apply`:

```
> apply( MyData , 2, quantile , .99 , na.rm = TRUE )
   X    Y    Z 
98.0 97.6 92.8 
> sapply( MyData , quantile , .99 , na.rm = TRUE )
X.99% Y.99% Z.99% 
 98.0  97.6  92.8
```

However, deleting the whole ROW if a value above this threshold is detected – and this for EACH column – is not working for me. Any solution – with or without `dplyr`is appreciated.

Comment: Use `cut` with the calculated quantiles as the `break` argument.

Comment: Above which threshold?

Comment: @Sam: in my example above I used .99. Something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `filter_all` from `dplyr` to filter rows for a condition for every columns. `all_vars` means all the columns needs to meet the condition.

```
set.seed(123)
MyData <- data.frame(
  X = sample(10:100, 21),
  Y = sample(10:100, 21),
  Z = sample(10:100, 21)
)

head(MyData)
#   X  Y  Z
# 1 36 73 47
# 2 80 67 43
# 3 46 98 23
# 4 87 99 22
# 5 91 71 30
# 6 13 56 50

library(dplyr)

MyData2 <- MyData %>% filter_all(all_vars(. <= quantile(., 0.99, na.rm = TRUE)))

head(MyData2)
#    X  Y  Z
# 1 36 73 47
# 2 80 67 43
# 3 46 98 23
# 4 91 71 30
# 5 13 56 50
# 6 54 60 32
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I didn't know very well how `filter_all` works. A good use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `cut`:

```r
set.seed(123)
MyData <- data.frame(
    X = sample(10:100, 21),
    Y = sample(10:100, 21),
    Z = sample(10:100, 21)
)
head(MyData, 4)
#>    X  Y  Z
#> 1 36 73 47
#> 2 80 67 43
#> 3 46 98 23
#> 4 87 99 22
apply(MyData, 2, quantile, .95)
#>  X  Y  Z 
#> 97 98 83
tmp1 <- apply(MyData, 2, function(x) cut(x, c(-Inf, quantile(x, probs = .95), Inf), labels = FALSE))
MyData[tmp1 == 2] <- NA
head(MyData, 4)
#>    X  Y  Z
#> 1 36 73 47
#> 2 80 67 43
#> 3 46 98 23
#> 4 87 NA 22
head(na.omit(MyData), 4)
#>    X  Y  Z
#> 1 36 73 47
#> 2 80 67 43
#> 3 46 98 23
#> 5 91 71 30
```

Comment: Thx. That was really good. My bad: I wasn't clear enough. I edited my question as I  want the whole row to get deleted. So in your case `> 4 87 NA 22`must be completed from the df. Any idea?

Comment: @AmirRahbaran `na.omit(MyData)` would remove any rows with `NA`.

Comment: Thx for your great answer. Upvoted your anwer and all your comments. I chose @www as the chosen answer as it solved the issue with literally one line of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare against the quantile to get a matrix of TRUE and FALSE, then subset the rows where no columns contains TRUE

```
MyData[!apply(apply(MyData, 2, function(x) x > quantile(x, 0.99)), 1, any), ]
```

data:

```
set.seed(26L)
MyData <- as.matrix(data.frame(
    X = sample(10:100, 21),
    Y = sample(10:100, 21),
    Z = sample(10:100, 21)
))
```